# Traefik behind ssl terminating load balancer return 404

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik

I have a K8s setup with traefik being exposed like this

```
kubernetes:
  ingressClass: traefik
service:
  nodePorts:
    http: 32080
serviceType: NodePort
```

Behind, I forward some requests to different services

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-name
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /my-first-path
            backend:
              serviceName: my-nodeJs-services
              servicePort: 3000
```

When the DNS is set directly to resolve to my ip, the application works fine with HTTP

http://my-host.com:32080/my-first-path

But when some one add SSL through AWS ALB / API Gateway, the application fail to be reached with 404-NotFound error

The route is like this
https://my-host.com/my-first-path

On the AWS size, they configured something like this

```
https://my-host.com => SSL Termination and  => Forward all to 43.43.43.43:32080
```

I think this fail because traefik is expecting http://my-host.com but not https://my-host.com which lead to its failure to find the matching route? Or maybe at the ssl termination time, the hostname is lost so that traefik can not find a route?

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with ALB but what is probably happening is that the requests received by the loadbalancer contain the header `Host: my-host.com` and when it gets forwarded to your ingress controller, the header is replaced by `Host: 43.43.43.43`. If this is the case, I see 3 solutions:

1. ALB might be able to pass the original Host header to the target. (You will have to check in the doc if it's possible)
2. If the application behind your ingress doesn't check the host header, you can write an ingress that doesn't check a specific host. For example on these [examples](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/user-guide/kubernetes/#traffic-splitting) you can see that the host field is not specified.
3. If the name resolution works internally, you can define a name for your target, use this name in your ALB and in your ingress.

Comment: Thank you. I follow your suggestion and alter/forward the correct host header. I did a bunch of small things also so not I do not know which particular part solve my problem but it works now, and it is certainly a right thing to forward the correct host !